# greek symbols in plot using matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot, printing, symbols

I am trying to plot a graph with `matplotlib(python)`
Is there any solution for this problem?

This is my code:

```
+u"\u0394
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Matplotlib supports Latex notation for text. Give it a try. It should make it possible: http://matplotlib.org/users/mathtext.html